# How to nest multiple css attributes inside another attribute

Tags: css

I am getting an html file as a string and I need to change the styling that are coming in to prevent it from changing the parent styling.

Instead of going through each style and changing it from

```
    .inner-div{height: 50px;}
```

to

```
    .outter-div .inner-div{height: 50px;}
```

on each element, I would like to do something like

```
    .outter-div {
        .inner-div{height: 50px;}
        .inner-div2{height: 50px;}
    }
```

however that does not work

Is there a way to have multiple attributes nested inside of another attribute, instead of having to add the parent on each attribute?

Comment: Nope, not unless you use a preprocessor such as LESS or SASS, which allow this syntax (but of course simply transform it to basic CSS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do something like that, you'd have to use a CSS pre-processor.

Two popular candidates are [Less](http://lesscss.org/) and [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/).

Less and Sass extend CSS to provide extra features, including the ability to nest multiple attributes. This Less or Sass code is then fed into a pre-processor, which transforms it into standard CSS that a browser understands and can be deployed as part of your website or app.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the inner class names all **start the same** (with 'inner'), then this can be done with an attribute selector. like this:

```
.outer-div [class^=inner] {
  height: 50px; 
}
```

### [Demo](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/NNPXJB)

If this is not the case, then...**use a CSS preprocessor** like others have mentioned.

**PS:** just for the record...

CSS selectors level 4 has added the `:matches` pseudo-class in order to group selectors more easily.

The syntax looks like this: `:matches( selector[, selector]* )`

In your case, it would be:

```
.outer-div :-matches(.inner-div, .inner-div2 ) {
        height: 50px;
}
```

You can read more about it [this CSS-tricks post](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/m/matches/)

**NB:**
Currently there is no browser support for `:matches`, **however** the :`matches` pseudo class was once called `:any` in the spec, supported with -moz- and -webkit- prefixes. See [MDN on :any](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:any)

Here's a working example for webkit using `:any`:

### [Codepen](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/qZEmVX)